# Looking for a webpage with chess puzzles in which you had to mentally play a couple moves before an interesting position arised

Tags: training, puzzles, websites, identify-this

As per the title; instead of the typical chess puzzle in which a side has to play and find the best move, you were given a couple moves and then were asked about the resulting position.

I guess I found it a couple years ago, lost track of it, and after some googling I've found nothing at all.

The idea is quite similar to the answer provided by @bramwhqb: https://listudy.org/en/blind-tactics/547

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean any couple of moves? Do you mean real chess games that may not have a clear solution?

Comment: @DanielAlfredoSottile, what I'm looking for is very similar to this study in lichess: https://listudy.org/en/blind-tactics/547

Comment: The book _Test Your Tactical Ability_ by Yakov Neishtadt includes some such puzzles with more variety though. However, most puzzles in it are just regular puzzles, but sometimes a move or two or even some lines are asked to be evaluated or what what would happen if such moves/lines had been played, etc. to make it easier rather than solving from the get-go. Good question. +1, although I wasn't aware of the website. And Neishtadt's book differs from it with only a minority of puzzles with such hints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean blindfold puzzles. The only site I know that has them is listudy: https://listudy.org/en/blind-tactics/547